# How to add mysql to newrelic monitoring in CloudFoundry App

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry, newrelic

I am trying to get my MySQL Server to show up in the New Relic Service Map (just like how redis shows up) using the MySQL Plugin(https://newrelic.com/plugins/new-relic-platform-team/52) but am unable to do so.

My app is running on CloudFoundry and i have been able to link the app to new-relic following instructions from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-new_relic_agent.md

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Add New Relic dependency in maven or gradle and bind with New Relic service instance. Then you have to restage the app to fetch New Relic dependency into the app.
Next you can find your app getting registered in New Relic dashboard.

You must have account in New Relic for managing the monitoring tool.